# unwanted button in each field of giridview

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I want to add one button in my gridview but when I drag and drop the button and run the project , I see that button is in each field of gridview...I tried some solutions like making 2 linear layout, and put the button in separate layout, but no change!
here is the code:

```
public class gridview extends Activity{
    GridView grid_main;
    Context context;
    TextView tv;
    EditText tx;
    ImageAdapter grid;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
       setContentView(R.layout.gridview);
        grid_main = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        grid_main.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        grid= new ImageAdapter(context);

//        grid_main.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  //          public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    //            grid .getCount();
      //          grid .getItem(position);
       // }
       // });


    }
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        Context mContext;
        public static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 10;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c){
            mContext = c;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v;
            if(convertView==null){
                     LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent, false);

                    tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    tx = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    tv.setText(""+R.drawable.download);
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);




            }
            else
            {
                v = convertView;
            }
            return v;
        }
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.french,
                R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.french,
                R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.french,
                R.drawable.french
        };
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

xml file:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="366dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

</GridView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="textview" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

 </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

```
    08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.finalproject3/com.example.finalproject3.gridview}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:477)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:750)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:365)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at com.example.finalproject3.gridview.onCreate(gridview.java:24)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
08-27 15:26:24.067: E/AndroidRuntime(26165):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: where are you put button .. so why use drag and drope..

Comment: question has been edited !

Comment: @eng.m.a , post your after apps screen by capture

Comment: Why are u using same layout in activity and adapter

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it ! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485203/gridview-with-edittext-and-imge-but-with-one-button/18532993#18532993

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it ! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485203/gridview-with-edittext-and-imge-but-with-one-button/18532993#18532993

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just want to have a GridLayout with your imageview, textview and textedit and underneath them your button? Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

   <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/download" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

    </GridLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
```

If you don't have Android 4.0 or higher, GridLayouts are not available. So then use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This solution will show the image on top.
Underneath a TextView ont he left and its EditText on the right
and on the bottom your button

Comment: I think u didn't get what my problem is :)
I don't want "button" to be in gridview !! I want it to be out of the gridview...so I put it in separate layout.

Comment: yes I want the same thin as you said , but when I copy your code , it got error for "gridlayout"

Comment: What is the error? Go with mouse over the red line and tell me what it says

Comment: View requires API level 14 (current min is 8): <GridLayout>

Comment: GridLayouts run only on android devices with min Android Version 4.0. I will edit the post for an Layout that runs on ur version.

Comment: sorry but I think your xml code is just for one image! and I used multiple images in my project...and also if there is a way for having multiple images withoud gridview (as your code shows) I have to change my java code because I've used gridview in it...do u have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Remove list item from grid layout xml .Use separate Layout for showing ListItem

gridview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="366dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

</GridView>

 </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Changed your adapter getView method

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v;
            if(convertView==null){                 

                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent, false);

                tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tx = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                tv.setText(""+R.drawable.download);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);



            }
            else
            {
                v = convertView;
            }
            return v;
        }
```

Comment: thanks but I get error in this line :
 LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();...the method "getlauoutinflater" does not defiend for the type context

Comment: I did this but when I run it, application force stops apears! :(

Comment: post your logcat exception